# Simultaneous progress bars

Tags: ruby, terminal

This script creates a pseudo progress bar:

```
bar, bar2 = '', ''
10.times do |i|
  bar << '='
  bar2 << '**'
  print "#{bar} - #{i+1}0%\r"
  #print "#{bar2} - #{i+1}0%\r"
  sleep 0.3
end
```

10 `=` appear in the bottom left of the screen before it completes.

I want to create two simultaneous loading bars. So as you can see, I've created `bar2` that creates 20 `*` before it completes.

**Both work fine, but not simultaneously!** If I uncomment both print commands, I print both bars, only the `bar2` is shown, `bar1` doesn't show up at all.

I'm guessing this is because the `\r` returns the "cursor" to the start of the line and overrides `bar` with `bar2`'s progress.

I've tried utilizing a `\n`, but all text preceding the `\n` is not wiped.  Again, this is because `\r` is carriage return that can't get before a new line, so while the first loop actually works perfectly, `bar`'s progress (and a `\n`) stays on the screen, causing this effect:

```
> = - 10%
> == - 20%
> === - 30%%
> ==== - 40%0%
> ===== - 50%40%
> ====== - 60% 50%
> ======= - 70%- 60%
> ======== - 80% - 70%
> ========= - 90%* - 80%
> ========== - 100%* - 90%
```

So how do I create two simultaneous loading bars? Or indeed an infinite number of simultaneous loading bars? I'm testing in `gnome-terminal` but I'd like a solution that works in most, if not all, modern terminals.

Comment: You'll probably have to roll your own using something like [ncurses](https://github.com/eclubb/ncurses-ruby) to handle the console cursor.

Looks like someone already made something that might be close to what you want, [multiple_progress_bar](https://github.com/Peeja/multi_progress_bar).  Uses ncurses.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty cool little problem. Basically, you got it right that you can overwrite the current line with `\r`. Now you just need a character, which can jump back to the previous line. You can use `"\033[F"` for that:

```
bar, bar2 = '', ''
10.times do |i|
  bar << '='
  bar2 << '**'
  puts  "#{bar} - #{i+1}0%"
  print "#{bar2} - #{i+1}0%"
  print "\033[F\r"
  sleep 0.3
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Given [@ndn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32851046/33226) I'm thinking that it may be system and/or shell specific. I used the control character `\033[1A` to move the cursor back one line:

```
# Tested on Mac & CentOS w/ Bash
bar, bar2 = '', ''
10.times do |i|
  bar << '='
  bar2 << '**'
  puts  "#{bar} - #{i+1}0%"
  print "#{bar2} - #{i+1}0%"
  print "\033[1A\r"
  sleep 0.3
end
```

You can use this [page on Cursor Movement](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) to do all sorts of things!

Comment: Both work for me. Does the `"\033[F"` version not work for you?

Comment: @ndn I'm thinking it's probably shell specific actually. What are you running?

Comment: `\033[F` (cursor-preceding-line) is not part of VT100, so its implementation in different terminals tends to be spotty (aside from [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)).  By the way, some of the sequences on the bash page likewise are not VT100 (the cursor save/restore).  The comment there about nxterm dates it back to the late 1990s (someone should maintain that page).